Related to the opamp question solution (a point I don't understand in the difference amplifier)
I greet everyone,
I am in the process of learning opamps, I got stuck here while solving a question about the difference amplifier.
When finding the Vo value, we do the following operation;
\$V_O = \left(\frac{-R_{13}}{R_{14}} \times V_X\right) + \frac{R_{16}}{R_{15} + R_{16}} \times \left(1 + \frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)\times V_Y = 4V + 4.5V = 8.5V\$
This is how it is solved. But I don't understand the logic of how we remove this part here;
\$ \frac{R_{16}}{R_{15} + R_{16}} \times \left(1 + \frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)\times V_Y\$
How can we remove this part? I would be grateful if someone from the community could explain


Please use mathml/TeX; it's hard to read the equations as written.

When you say this: R16 / R15 + R16 don't you actually mean this: $\dfrac{R_{16}}{R_{15} + R_{16}}$? ----> \$\dfrac{R_{16}}{R_{15} + R_{16}}\$

I don't see it removed. You still calculate something related to Vx and something related to Vy and sum them together. Please explain what you mean.

Remove? We do not remove anything? What you see is a superposition principle in action.

@Andy , yes that's exactly what I mean, I added it as latex but it didn't convert.

Can you elaborate on your question more? Because in the calculations you have shown we do not remove anything. Since Vy = 6V, we have a +3V due to voltage divider action at the non-inverting input and this voltage will be amplified by 1.5 factor. Thus, we have 3V * 1.5V = 4.5V and this voltage will be superimposed on the voltage we get from an inverting amplifier (-8V * -0.5 = 4V).

Your question is not very precise.
I can only guess, what you want.
The opamp circuit you have drawn delivers:
Vo = ky * Vy - kx * Vx

Would you like to know how to calculate ky and kx from R13 - R16 - or even, when kx = ky?
The special case kx = ky happens always when:
R13 / R14 = R16 / R15

then even
kx = R13 / R14
ky = R16 / R15

You'd like to know how to convert your complex start formula until you get this reduction? I did it here:

With that we get the circuit parametrization:
k = R13 / R14 = R16 / R15

and
Vo = k * (Vy - Vx)


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
PS: if you choose kx not the same as ky then the formula stays complex!

Trying to read between the lines, I think you are wondering how \$\left(1+\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)\$ gets removed from the \$V_x\$ term in the equation. Perhaps the confusion so far is that you cited the \$V_y\$ term that shows this factor, but you are wondering why you don't also see the same factor with the \$V_x\$ term.
I may be totally wrong about that. But that's my guess.
By superposition, you know that:
$$V_-=V_x\cdot\frac{R_{13}}{R_{13}+R_{14}}+V_o\cdot\frac{R_{14}}{R_{13}+R_{14}}$$
You also know that:
$$V_+=V_y\cdot\frac{R_{16}}{R_{15}+R_{16}}$$
And those are equal:
$$V_x\cdot\frac{R_{13}}{R_{13}+R_{14}}+V_o\cdot\frac{R_{14}}{R_{13}+R_{14}}=V_y\cdot\frac{R_{16}}{R_{15}+R_{16}}$$
Multiplying through by \$\frac{R_{13}+R_{14}}{R_{14}}=\left(1+\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)\$, another way to look at this is:
$$\begin{align*}V_o&=\left[-V_x\cdot\frac{R_{13}}{R_{13}+R_{14}}+V_y\cdot\frac{R_{16}}{R_{15}+R_{16}}\right]\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)\\\\&=-V_x\cdot\underbrace{\frac{R_{13}}{R_{13}+R_{14}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)}_\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}+V_y\cdot\frac{R_{16}}{R_{15}+R_{16}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)\\\\&=-V_x\cdot\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}+V_y\cdot\frac{R_{16}}{R_{15}+R_{16}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_{13}}{R_{14}}\right)\end{align*}$$
Not sure if that addresses your question. But it's the best guess I have at this time.
